# Unable to get value of the property 'match': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I'm getting "Unable to get value of the property 'match': object is null or undefined" when the function below works. The interesting part is that it is working perfectly on another page. Any ideas?

```
function valPoBox(sender, args) {
    var hasPObox = /^[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\s*(\d.)*/gi;
    var StreetAddress = $('.streetaddress').val();

    if (StreetAddress.match(hasPObox)) {
        args.IsValid = false;

        sender.ErrorMessage = "Address must not contain P.O. Box";
        $('.valPoBox').attr("ErrorMessage", sender.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely `$('.streetaddress').val()` returns undefined due to not finding any elements. Confirm with `console.log($('.streetaddress').val())` and `console.log($('.streetaddress').length)`

Comment: nailed it. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All strings have a `match` method, therefore what you are dealing with must not be a string. the `.val()` method only returns two different things: a string when an element is found, and `undefined` when an element is not found. With this in mind, `$('.streetaddress')` must be returning 0 elements. Modify the selector so that it targets the correct elements to fix the issue.